# In Postgres, is it possible to filter out rows with an array column whose value is a subset of values contained in other rows using sql

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I want to shorten this result to only return rows that have a superset of all the rows and order of numbers in the chain column matters

Better to think of this as paths for example in an ltree (but dynamically generated-- in this case using a recursive cte)

```
si_id   chain
5   {3,5}
5   {4,5}
5   {8,5}
2   {3,2}
2   {4,2}
1   {3,2,1}
1   {3,5,1}
1   {4,2,1}
1   {4,5,1}
1   {8,5,1}
```

edited to show expected output:

```
{3,2,1}
{3,5,1}
{4,2,1}
{8,5,1}
{4,5,1}
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: {3,5,1}
{8,5,1}
{4,2,1}
{3,2,1}
{4,5,1}

Comment: This is expected result when use `'{3,5}'` as 'superset' for example in your question? Results must contain 3 in first element or 5 in second? Why in result present '{4,2,1}'?

Comment: the example was just to illustrate that the ordering was significant .. i'll edit the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: With which parameter applied to first table you receive expected output?

Comment: I am looking to suppress rows with chains  that are contained in other (longer) chains

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WITH search AS (
    SELECT '{3,5,1}'::int4[] AS search,
           array_upper( '{3,5,1}'::int4[], 1) AS search_len
)
SELECT *
FROM s
JOIN search ON ( chain @> search)
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM generate_series(1, array_upper(chain, 1) - search_len + 1) AS i
        WHERE chain[i:(search_len + i - 1)] = search
)
```

Comment: this returns the same result as the value in the cte and if i change the value to {3} it returns non-supersets also

i added a comment on the question about what the desired output would be

thanks!